# Azure Function with authentication to Dynamic 365 - Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng'

Tags: c#, azure, function, authentication

I have an azure function / App registrations that is working until I try to use Authentication to get a token.  I am getting the following error message using the following code.

```
var requestedToken = authenticationResult.Result.AccessToken;
```

There is an issue while generating `idOne` or more errors occurred. (Could not load type `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng` from assembly `System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`)

```
var aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";

string api = "https://interconservicesdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1";

AuthenticationParameters ap = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromUrlAsync(
    new Uri(api)).Result;

string organizationUrl = "https://interconservicesdevdev.crm.dynamics.com";
string clientId = "SOME_CLIENT_ID";
string secertKey = "SOME_SECRET_KEY";
string tenantId = "SOME_TENANT_ID";

log.Info("Organization Url : " + organizationUrl);
log.Info("Client Id : " + clientId);
log.Info("Client Key : " + secertKey);
log.Info("Tenant Id : " + tenantId);

var clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, secertKey);
string combineString = aadInstance + tenantId;
log.Info("Combine String : " + combineString);

var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(combineString, false);

log.Info("Authority : " + authenticationContext.Authority);

//AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(organizationUrl, clientcred);
log.Info("Authentication Result : " + authenticationResult.IsCompleted + " " + authenticationResult.Id);

var requestedToken = authenticationResult.Result.AccessToken;
log.Info("Requested Token : " + requestedToken);

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

service = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(GetServiceUrl(organizationUrl), new TimeSpan(0, 180, 0), false);
log.Info("Service : " + service.SdkClientVersion);
service.HeaderToken = requestedToken;

log.Info("Header Token : " + requestedToken);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Robert! I strongly suggest you edit the IDs/keys our of your posts and rotate the ones that you have displayed here.

Comment: Hi SamaraSoucy thanks for responding.  I am not understanding what you mean by rotating the ones.  The key and ID are not what I have added to this post.

Comment: Under Certificats & Secrets is where your keys are accessed in the Azure portal. Removing the one you've displayed here and creating a new one will prevent malicious use. Best practice is to change keys on a scheduled basis or "rotate" them as a preventative measure.

If that isn't the real secret then you are fine. :)

Comment: I am having the same issue for the exactly same scenario, although I cannot deploy from VisualStudio due to organization security restrictions. Any help for solving the problem from Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve my issue from changing over from VS 2017 to 2019.